# filtering from list as query string postgresql flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am passing list as a query string and i want to retrieve data from database with the value of all the list value.The list value represents the value of a column.My code look something like this:

```
companylist=['a','b','c']
sql = text("""select * from company_data cd  where cd.company_id=:companyId""")
priceItem = connection.execute(sql, id=id, companyId=companylist).fetchAll()
```

This is how table looks like:

```
create table company_data
(
    id    varchar(255) primary key,
    company_id   text,
    price    text,
    volume text
);
```

All i want is filter all the value based on value from the  list from database and also the list cannot be greater than 20.How can i resolve this?

Comment: company_id in database is a list or foreign_key (int) to another table?

Comment: its not a foreign key.Its just a column. companylist holds the value of some company column i want to filter

Comment: Can you show how your company_data table schema (columns with types)?

Comment: question is updated

Answer (score 0):

I am not understand about that `text()` and insert the value inside an `execute()`, here I make it to a sql command in string format.

```
companylist=['a','b','c']
sql = ("""select * from company_data cd  where cd.company_id = ANY(ARRAY{})""".format(companylist))
priceItem = connection.execute(sql).fetchAll()
```

This is refer to

`WHERE column = ANY(ARRAY([a, r, r, a, y]))`